# Specifying controller in directive definition does not create new scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I ran across a rather un-intuitive aspect of AngularJS directives and I'm curious if there's a logical reason for this behavior.  When I specify a controller in a directive's definition:

```
angular.module('MyApp.directives', [])
    .directive('myDirective, function () {
        templateUrl: "my-template.html",
        controller: "MyController"
    };
```

the scope of the directive's template is the same for all instances of the directive.

However, if I *don't* specify a controller in the directive's definition:

```
angular.module('MyApp.directives', [])
    .directive('myDirective, function () {
        templateUrl: "my-template.html"
    };
```

and instead define the controller directly on the directive using `ng-controller`:

```
<my-directive ng-controller="MyController"/>
```

each instance of `MyController` receives its own child scope.

I expected these approaches to yield the same results, but apparently Angular treats the controller's scope differently depending on how the controller is declared.  Is there a reason for this difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this, I believe, is the fact that the directive as a definition is a singleton. So when you enter a controller as a property on singleton's return object, it is shared for all the instances.

But when you define the markup with ng-controller, the ng-controller directive instantiates that controller on each element, so it creates a new controller (and thus a new scope) for every directive instance.